# How to get a few Products from a store satisfying some string using rest API?

Tags: javascript, rest, magento, postman

I want to get 4 products from Magento store. These items contain "**food**" string in their SKUs. SKU can be something like "**FoodDietic**", "**TastyFood**" and so on. I have done a research to understand how to use the *searchCriteria* but I still can not. This is the request I used but it is not what I need.

```
https://magento.am/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_gear&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=86&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=finset&fields=items[sku,price,name]
```

What kind of get request should I send to get all my 4 Items?

Here is what I have read: [Magento Get Request](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/get-all-products-orders-categories-magento-2.html)

Comment: What you mean by "what kind of `GET` request..." there is only that one `GET` HTTP request method and you can use Fetch API to make the request.

Comment: I meant how to form a query link.

Comment: So you want to create a dynamic link? You should wrap your link in a template literals (backticks `\``) and you can pass an expression in place of your hardcoded key-value pairs by wrapping it in a `${` and `}` so to your key=value pairs of your query part of the URL you will replace either or both with an `${expression}` as per your needs.